# how to handle Third party API

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, webapi

I have my api created, which internally calls third party api (for which i will refer their api). when their api returns success result (status code 200) and data, i am saving it to database and myapi will also returns 200 status code.
But when their api returns statuscode other than 200 (like- statusCode 401, statusCode 403) then how to handle that in myapi?
plus, in this case myapi should return 200 statuscode or should return the same statusCode which their api returns, if yes How to do that.?

i need to show different toasters on client side based on what response their api returns in angular? how to do that.

i am new to asp.net core web api so can someone help me.

here is my api -

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddStudent(student stud)
        {
                 Student Student = await _empRepo.AddOrUpdateStudent(stud);
                   return new OkObjectResult(student)
        }
```

In the Repo -

```
     public async Task<object> AddOrUpdateStudent(student stud)
      {
                var response= await testapi.getexternalstudentdata(student.Id);
            if(response is Student)
            {
              //save data in database
              // return the same object which saved in DB
            }
        else{
              // what should i do here to return whatever error i am getting to client in asp .net core 3.1
            }
      }
```

calling third party api-

```
 public async Task<object> getexternalstudentdata(int StudId)
        {
            var relativePath = "url"
            var response = await SendAsync(HttpMethod.Get, relativePath);
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return response;
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(responseString);
        }
```

here is sendAsync Method -

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpMethod method, string relativePath)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, _httpClient.BaseAddress + relativePath);
           
            return await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        }
```

Comment: Can you paste the code of getexternalstudentdata?

Comment: Response of an api (theirs) would contain the status code in it. Besides the property issuccessStatusCode, check for the actual StatusCode in response (200, 401 etc)

Comment: @jawad yes it is returning status code as well, how to handle that